# How to redirect to a another page in reactjs when switch case statement used or redirect to another page inside navbar react routev6 & switch case?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, routes, navbar

Navbar routing by executing  switch case statement , useNavigation of react router v6

Check this in the documentation https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function MuiNavbar() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

const handleTabSwitch = (value) => {
    setActiveTab(value);

switch (value) {
  case 0:
      return navigate("/");
  case 1:
      return navigate("/learn");
  case 2:
      return navigate("/practise");
  case 3:
      return navigate("/play");
  default:
      return null
  }
  };
return ( .... )
```

Comment: I guess `return` statement for each `case` isn't required here and adding `break` would be fine ....

Comment: I would suggest to put that switch statement to useEffect hook. Now any change of your application state will lead to redirect.